# Regex to replace text enclosed in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

The runtime is NodeJS, I'm trying to replace the text `$Contact` with a name. But I also need the ability to capture words around the term enclosed in curly brackets `{}`:

```
Where Name = John:
  My name is $Contact => My name is John
  Hello {I am $Contact} => Hello I am John

Where Name = null:
  My name is $Contact => My name is 
  Hello {I am $Contact} => Hello
```

The idea is to replace the `$Contact` qualifier with a string, and OPTIONALLY the text enclosed in brackets is only displayed if the string is not empty. The use of curly brackets is optional.

```
// m = Message template (Hello {I am $Contact})
// qualifier = $Contact
// value = value to replace with

const replaceQualifier = (m, qualifier, value) =>
    m.replace(new RegExp('\\{?(.*?)\\' + qualifier + '(.*?)\\}?', 'g'), value ? `$1${value}$2` : '');
```

It seems to work for qualifiers without curly brackets but not with curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```js
var str1 = "My name is $Contact"
var str2 = "My name is {$Contact}"
var str3 = "Hello {I am $Contact}"

const replaceQualifier = (m, qualifier, value) =>
    m.replace(new RegExp(`(?:\\{(.*?))?\\${qualifier}(?:(.*?)\\})?`), value ? `$1${value}$2` : '');

console.log(replaceQualifier(str1,"$Contact","John"))
console.log(replaceQualifier(str2,"$Contact","John"))
console.log(replaceQualifier(str3,"$Contact","John"))
console.log(replaceQualifier(str1,"$Contact"))
console.log(replaceQualifier(str2,"$Contact"))
console.log(replaceQualifier(str3,"$Contact"))
```

Output:

```
My name is John
My name is John
Hello I am John
My name is 
My name is 
Hello
```

The solution is very similar to yours, just the groups are used differently:

- `(?...)` ... non-capturing ("plain") parentheses
- `\\{(.*?)` ... `{` followed by a captured group `(.*?)`
- `(?:\\{(.*?))?` ... present zero or more times
- similarly for the right part

**EDIT** (why the original regex did not work)

while debugging `replace`, look first what is `match`ed, for debugging purposes without the `g` flag.
In this case, `\{?(.*?)` = **optional** `{` character, then (grouped) zero or more of **any** character and then the `qualifier`, i.e. the group is **entire string** before `qualifier` (because the `{` is *optional*)

In the proposed solution, the **entire block** `\{(.*?)` is made optional, i.e. matching the `{...` part of the string if present, but does not match anything otherwise.

Comment: So basically you've grouped `{` and `(.*?)` together. Any idea why my regex didn't work, I thought I was making both `{` and `(.*?)` optional separately.

Comment: @rosghub I have edited my answer. The point is that the original regex matches entire first part of the string, the proposed solution just the `{...` part or nothing

Comment: Ah I see that explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @rosghub The use of `.*?` that matches any kind of chars other than line break chars always causes unexpected results when there are no 3rd string occurrences between two delimiters. If there is no `$Contact` in between `{...}`, matching goes on until a match is found. See [what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/Ss88DF/1). [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996079/3832970) is to use a more restrictive pattern than a `.`: either negated character classes, or tempered greedy tokens (when the delimiter pattern is multicharacter).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
m.replace(new RegExp('(?:\\{([^{}]*))?\\' + qualifier + '(?:([^{}]*)})?', 'g'), 
   value ? `$1${value}$2` : '');
```

The regex will look like

```
(?:\{([^{}]*))?\$Contact(?:([^{}]*)})?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tDvBIW/1). **Details**:

- `(?:\{([^{}]*))?` - an optional occurrence of `{` and then (Group 1) any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `\$Contact` - `$Contact`
- `(?:([^{}]*)})?` - an optional occurrence of (Group 2) any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then `}`.

See the JS demo:

```js
const replaceQualifier = (m, qualifier, value) =>
    m.replace(new RegExp('(?:\\{([^{}]*))?\\' + qualifier + '(?:([^{}]*)})?', 'g'), value ? `$1${value}$2` : '');

const qualifier = '$Contact';
let m = 'Hello {I am $Contact}';
let value = 'John';
console.log(replaceQualifier(m, qualifier, value));
value = '';
console.log(replaceQualifier(m, qualifier, value));

m = 'My name is $Contact';
value = 'John';
console.log(replaceQualifier(m, qualifier, value));
value = '';
console.log(replaceQualifier(m, qualifier, value));
```